# Utilizar la GPU para calcular la transferencia de entropía con la librería PyIF de python

Tags: python, numpy, gpu

Estoy calculando la transferencia de entropía usando la librería PyIF de Python.

El código es el siguiente:

```
from PyIF import te_compute as te

import numpy as np

rand = np.random.RandomState(seed=23)

X_1000000 = rand.randn(1000000, 1).flatten()

Y_1000000 = rand.randn(1000000, 1).flatten()

TE = te.te_compute(X_1000, Y_1000, k=1, embedding=1, safetyCheck=True, GPU=True)

print(TE)
```

Al final de la penúltima línea se puede apreciar que pongo: `GPU=True`. Según la documentación, esto basta para que el computador use la GPU en vez de la CPU, pero al correr el código no muestra ningún cambio en la velocidad de procesamiento y tampoco se refleja en el consumo de la GPU al ver el administrador de tareas.

¿Cómo hacer para que la librería use la GPU de mi computador?

Estoy usando notebook de Anaconda e instalé CUDA en este entorno.

Comment: que gpu tienes?

puede que sea el caso como keras (si no mal lo recuerdo) que con gpu intel no funcionaba igual, de hecho corria a la misma velocidad que con el cpu, pero con un NVIDIA era mas que suficiente

Comment: Hola, o sea mi tarjeta gráfica es la nvidia geforce gtx 1060 with max-q design.

Comment: y sí, al momento de ver el consumo no se nota para nada que la GPU esté haciendo algo de su trabajo, sino solo la CPU y como te digo, tengo la NVIDIA.

Comment: por lo que he revisado, todo esta correcto la libreria como tal no tiene mucha documentacion, bueno al menos yo no la he encontrado mas que en pip...

Comment: que es lo que intentas hacer igual y otra libreria te serviria muy bien

Comment: pues intento calcular la transferencia de entropía entre pares de vectores. El problema es que tengo como 6 millones y medio de estos pares y por cada par se demora 1 segundos aproximadamente. No quiero esperar 6 millones de segundos. :/ Es por eso motivo que intento usar la GPU de mi computadora para mejor los tiempos pero parece que no hay diferencia cuando pongo True o False en el parámetro de la GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código está perfecto, siguiendo los comentarios de Christian es un paquete sin documentación y casí ningún seguimiento en [Github](https://github.com/lcdm-uiuc/PyIF). Por lo que te recomendaría que buscases otro paquete.

De hecho entrando en su código se puede ver que solo utilizan la GPU cuando crean [esta función](https://github.com/lcdm-uiuc/PyIF/blob/master/PyIF/GPU_TE.py). Están utilizando `Numba` que es una librería usada para la optimización de velocidad, lo hace traduciendo Python directamente a lenguaje de máquina.

Como se puede ver, el decorador `@cuda.jit` es el encargado de compilar y pasar a lenguaje de máquina el código. Pero lo hacen en una **función que solo realiza un conteo y una agregación**. Esto me atrevería a decir que incluso **puede hacer más lento el uso con GPU** por el movimiento de datos extra que tiene que haber entre las distintas partes del ordenador, para una operación tan sencilla.

**En resumen, es normal que no notes diferencia entre usar la GPU o no usarla.**

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, tu análisis me sirvió un montón. Una disculpa por no darte las gracias en su momento pero lo hago ahora.